# Three JS Circle Line Geom Color for Negative Values

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've been testing some ideas on how to get a circle to have a different color for the part of the circle that has positive Z values. I tried one approach, creating two separate line segments and using different materials. It works if the circle has segments that don't jump across Z=0. The problem I'm working on is more complicated as the line segments will jump across the Z=0 boundary so I end up with gaps if I try to do it in two segments. Is there a way to just use one line Geom and then change the color of the part of the line that falls into negative Z values? I'm not sure this is the right approach. Thanks!

Here is what I have so far for a test (using X,Y):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cirle Color</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script src="three.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 500, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100000 );

            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                var segmentCount = 100,
                    radius = 10,
                    geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
                    geometry2 = new THREE.Geometry();
                    material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: "#5fd119" }); // light green
                    material2 = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: "#3d8710" }); // darker green

                    //PUSH THE ORIGIN VERTICY IN
                    geometry2.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-10,0,0));

                for (var i = 0; i <= segmentCount; i++) {
                    var theta = (i / segmentCount) * Math.PI * 2;

                    x = Math.cos(theta) * radius;
                    y = Math.sin(theta) * radius;
                    z = 0;

                    if (y >=0 ){
                        geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z));  
                    } else {
                        geometry2.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z));
                    }          
                }

                scene.add(new THREE.Line(geometry, material));
                scene.add(new THREE.Line(geometry2, material2));

            camera.position.z = 5;

            var render = function () {
                requestAnimationFrame( render );

                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            };

            render();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Update using the answer below. Works great:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I get you correctly. You can set colours of vertices of a geometry and then use `vertexColors` parameter of a material.

```
  var radius = 5;
  var shape = new THREE.Shape();
  shape.moveTo(radius, 0);
  shape.absarc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  var spacedPoints = shape.createSpacedPointsGeometry(360);

  var vertexColors = []; // array for our vertex colours
  spacedPoints.vertices.forEach( function( vertex ){ // fill the array
    if( vertex.y < 0 )
      vertexColors.push( new THREE.Color( 0xff0000 ))
    else
      vertexColors.push( new THREE.Color( 0x0000ff ));
  });
  spacedPoints.colors = vertexColors; // assign the array

  var orbit = new THREE.Line(spacedPoints, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors // set this parameter like it shown here
  }));
  scene.add(orbit);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/40h2byh1/) example

Comment: With some tweaking I was able to integrate this into my project. EXACTLY what I wanted, thank you!!!

Comment: Thanks, three js app for viewing real asteroid orbits. :)
http://rankinstudio.com/Asteroid_Orbit_View